# DIV not displaying at top of page

Tags: html, css

I've created a basic layout and on the page are 2 links, one register and one login button.

Take a look at my jsfiddle link to see how it looks. There's a black box which will be the logo and you will see the green and blue boxes which are my buttons.

I need them at the top of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/4EZa5/

Not sure what I need to do to the CSS to make the links sit at the top of the very page?

HTML:

```
<div id="accountLinks">
 <ul>
<li class="login"><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
<li class="register"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#accountLinks{
float: right;
height:20px;
width: 170px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
 #accountLinks ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
 #accountLinks li{
float: left;
text-align: center;
 }
 #accountLinks .login{
background: url(../images/button_login.gif) no-repeat;
width: 70px;
height: 20px;
color: #FFF;    
  }
 #accountLinks .register{
background: url(../images/button_register.gif) no-repeat;
width: 70px;
height: 20px;
color: #FFF;    
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: [redacted] now i understand the issue. Sorry, still waking up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your H1 tag is a block element and is pushing the rest down. Just add float: left; to h1 css

```
h1{
width: 351px;
height: 49px;
background: #000;
text-indent: -9999px;
float: left;
}
```

To style the link only in login:

```
#accountLinks .login a {
    color: #FFF;    
}
#accountLinks .login a:hover {
    color: yellow;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great - worked a treat. Curious about something else on the page too which I forgot to mention wasn't working for me. 

On #accountLinks .login in the CSS, if I change it to #accountLinks .login a:link that doesn't seem to work to style the link. Thought that would work?

Comment: That should work I think you want the hover effect. I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

They're being pushed down by the `<h1>Salesboard</h1>` - is it possible to move that to just *after* the accountLinks div, or does that need to stay before them in the HTML?

If so, then this should fix the accountLinks:

```
#accountLinks{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height:20px;
    width: 170px;
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2T5/

Comment: This is the perfect...example of a comment.

Comment: Not really, I was working on the CSS, just giving him one possibility to be thinking about while I did that :) Updated post with the CSS just now.

Comment: Joe, with the update it's a much better solution, agreed. Posting an answer with just another question, however, is better served with a comment.

Comment: I'll bear that in mind for the future :) Out of interest, is there something on the SO meta which says what's better as a comment, what's better as an answer? They seem very similar to a new user :)

Comment: Hover over the "Add comment" link. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't see your links,  because they were floating left! underneath your css-styled  Salesboard

Additionally your `text-intend (9999)` is such that no text will be shown.

**Solution**
Newer browsers offer, the attribute fixed which will do exactly as it says.

Add this `"position: fixed;"`

```
#accountLinks{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height:20px;
    width: 170px;
}

#Container{
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a style next to the id="accountLinks" this will be easier to position you div which contains the login etc..

```
<h1>Salesboard</h1>
<div id="accountLinks" style="margin-top:-45px;">
<ul>
<li class="login"><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
<li class="register"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply place h1 at the bottom of #header.